# Semantic UI - How do I use sticky in modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, semantic-ui

I'm using semantic-ui and i'm having a problem with the sticky component.

I can get it to work in a normal page but I can't get it to work in a modal window.

I'm using :

HTML:

```
    <div class="ui modal">
        <div class="header">Title</div>
        <div class="scrolling content">
            <div class="ui sticky">
            ... content I want to have stick ...
        </div>
```

JS:

```
    $('.ui.sticky')
        .sticky('refresh')
    ;

    $('.ui.sticky')
        .sticky({
            type: 'fixed',
            offset: 200
        })
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing sticky behavior before the element is even visible yet, cause you're using modal , to prevent that from happening, use `onVisible` callback to start sticky behavior like the following :

[[DEMO]](https://codepen.io/SaadRegal/pen/PRdrom)

**JS(jQuery)**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.ui.modal').modal('show').modal({
      onVisible:$('.ui.sticky').sticky({
            type: 'fixed',
            offset: 200
        }).sticky('refresh')
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui modal">
    <div class="header">Title</div>
    <div class="scrolling content" style="min-height:1000px">
        <div class="ui sticky"> ... content I want to have stick ... </div>
    </div>
</div>
```